# Storing variable from void method

Tags: objective-c

I have a method like this:

```
- (void) advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser
didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
               withContext:(NSData *)context
         invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept,
                                    MCSession *session))invitationHandler{
```

and I need to copy and store the invitationHandler. It will be used later use in the following way:

```
invitationHandler(accept, session);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an instance variable to your class (not a property), and store it there. At your class definition:

```
@implementation MyClass {
  void(^invHandler)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session);
}
```

In your method, store it:

```
invHandler = Block_copy(invitationHandler);
```

And later, when you want to call it:

```
invHandler(accept, session);
```

Comment: Why do you specify 'not a property'?

Comment: @sapi: So that the value isn't public. I assumed that it isn't supposed to be.

Comment: Wouldn't you normally use a class extension for that, and put the property there?

Comment: Yes, in a case like that I would put it in a class extension and make it a property. Also, it should be `@interface` - `@class` is only used for forward declarations.

Comment: @zpasternack: whoops. Thinking in Ruby ;)